# Worried about my sapling

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So I just started playing, and I decided to plant my perfect fruit. After planting it, I got worried that I put it too close to my tent (My house will be complete tomorrow because I paid my down payment today). Does this seem too close?

[image: Sapling behind a tent]

Comment: What are you concerned about? That you won't be able to see the tree? The house will only take up the amount of space that's roped-off, so it won't destroy the tree or anything.

Answer (score 1):

In that place, the tree should be safe. Trees must be planted with at least one free space between it and any other object. There appears to be adequate room here.